# How to select objects with same dimensions in Object Mode

Tags: selection-tools

I often duplicate objects when building a trade show booth. How can I select objects with the same dimension?

In this example, I want to select all objects that have X: 95.2, Y: 2.44, Z: 39.1 as their dimension.

[image: Select]

I tried using the select options in Object Mode but was not able to find one that works for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Maybe from the beginning you should have linked duplicated these similar objects, in that case you could easily select them with a Shift L (Select Linked) > Object Data

Comment: @moonboots Thanks, that does work, feel free to submit that as an answer. I would prefer being able to skip linking the object data, but it does work. I would just have to get used to doing that every time I duplicate the object.

Comment: I often choose to put things in different collections in order to be able to select them via the collection they are in. Objects can be in more than one collection. With `M` you move a selected object exclusively to one collection, but with `Shift`+`M` you can link it to an additional collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following script will select objects that are close in dimensions to the active object, given some epsilon value.

You can run that or save the script and install it as addon.

Comments below to explain how it works.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Select similar dimensions",
    "author": "lemon",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Select > Select similar dimensions",
    "description": "Select objects that have similar dimensions compared to the active object",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Select Object",
}

import bpy

# loop over objects testing if their dimension is similar to a given object
# if similar, the objects are selected
def select_similar_dimensions(object, others, epsilon):
    
    # test the dimensions with an epsilon value
    def similar_dimensions(d, d_other, epsilon):
        delta = d - d_other
        return abs(delta.x) <= epsilon and abs(delta.y) <= epsilon and abs(delta.z) <= epsilon

    # get object dimension    
    dimensions = object.dimensions
    # loop over all objects
    for o in others:
        # select the one that are close in dimensions
        o.select_set(similar_dimensions(dimensions, o.dimensions, epsilon))


# the parts below are from "operator simple template"
# ...(adapted for our operator)

def main(context, epsilon):
    select_similar_dimensions(context.active_object, context.view_layer.objects, epsilon)


class SelectSimilarDimensions(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Select objects that have similar dimension compared to the active object"""
    bl_idname = "object.select_similar_dimensions"
    bl_label = "Select similar dimensions"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    epsilon: bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=0.001)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context, self.epsilon)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SelectSimilarDimensions.bl_idname, text=SelectSimilarDimensions.bl_label)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SelectSimilarDimensions)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SelectSimilarDimensions)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

When you duplicate your object, use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> so that the objects share the same mesh, this way you can easily select them with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> *(Select Linked) > Object Data*.